# Magento How to copy products of subcategories in parent category

Tags: magento, backend, categories

I want put all the products are in children categories in the parent category that contains. Is that posible?

Comment: hi and welcome to SO .what efforts have you made to find that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you must set the parent category as anchor.

To do that select the parent category (from the Catalog -> Manage Categories), and go to Display settings tab. In there, select the value Yes to Is Anchor field.

That will be all.